# Can't do an AJAX Request inside an AJAX Request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do an AJAX Request inside an AJAX Request, but for some reason, it won't be executed.

Its in the success callback function of the first request, and if I debug it in chrome, it never gets there, although the first request is properly executed.

Here is my code:

```
$.get(baseUrl + '/Home/AddUser?name=' + response.name + '&id=' + response.id, function (data) {
    if (data.error) {
        alert("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte melden sie dies den Entwicklern.<br />" + data.error);
        top.location.href = facebookUrl;
        return;
    }

    // Get Sweepstake and add UserToSweepstake
    if ($("input:radio").length == 0) {
        window.sweepstakeId = $("selected-sweepstake").attr("value");
    } else {
        window.sweepstakeId = $("input[type=radio]:checked").attr("id");
    }
    $.get(baseUrl + '/Home/AddUserToSweepstake?userId=' + data.id + '&sweepstakeId=' + window.sweepstakeId, function (innerData) {
        if (innerData.error) {
            alert("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte melden sie dies den Entwicklern.<br />" + innerData.error);
            top.location.href = facebookUrl;
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is the "outer" `success` callback executed at all?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this. Are you 100% sure it actually gets to the line where the second request is made? Can you do an alert there?

Comment: It doesnt get to the line, that is what I'm wondering about...
The request is definitly a success, but for some reason the success callback isnt firing...

Comment: *The request is definitly a success* ... how do you know? If it was, the callback would be called. It seems you are returning JSON. Is it valid? Does it get parsed? jQuery only parses JSON automatically if the content type is set correctly.

Comment: Really seems to be a problem with the JSON, I will check this...

Comment: My JSON was invalid.
The code works now.

I will remember to use " and not '-Quotes in JSON in the future :)

Cant self answer this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace that code with this and ensure there is not connection errors:

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + '/Home/AddUser?name=' + response.name + '&id=' + response.id,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        if (data.error) {
            alert("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte melden sie dies den Entwicklern.<br />" + data.error);
            top.location.href = facebookUrl;
            return;
        }

        // Get Sweepstake and add UserToSweepstake
        if ($("input:radio").length == 0) {
            window.sweepstakeId = $("selected-sweepstake").attr("value");
        } else {
            window.sweepstakeId = $("input[type=radio]:checked").attr("id");
        }
        $.get(baseUrl + '/Home/AddUserToSweepstake?userId=' + data.id + '&sweepstakeId=' + window.sweepstakeId, function (innerData) {
            if (innerData.error) {
                alert("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte melden sie dies den Entwicklern.<br />" + innerData.error);
                top.location.href = facebookUrl;
                return;
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + '/Home/AddUserToSweepstake?userId=' + data.id + '&sweepstakeId=' + window.sweepstakeId,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (innerData, itextStatus, ijqXHR) {
                if (innerData.error) {
                    alert("Es ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte melden sie dies den Entwicklern.<br />" + innerData.error);
                    top.location.href = facebookUrl;
                    return;
                }
            },
            error: function (idata, itextStatus, ijqXHR) {
                alert('connection error! ' + itextStatus);
            }
        });
    },
    error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert('connection error! ' + textStatus);
    }
});
```

Cheers.

Comment: I already did this, but couldn't answer the question myself... Thanks anyway.